# What type does eof return?

Tags: c++, types

Both [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits/eof) and [cplusplus.com](https://cplusplus.com/reference/string/char_traits/eof/) say it's `int_type`. But they don't explain (at least I couldn't find it, an neither could Bing Chat) what type it is. (I suppose it can be any signed integer type at least as wide as `char` and `bool`.)

Comment: And the overview page for `char_traits` shows what `int_type` is for the standard-provided specializations: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits

Comment: The cplusplus.com page describes what it returns quite well. What has you confused?

Comment: It returns an integer-type which is different from `char`.

Comment: And why do you wonder? Is it plain curiosity, or is it some other underlying problem leading to this question? In either case you should state the reason inside your question.

Comment: Wait, are you looking for the exact type? That's not specified. All the Standard requires is that the return type be large enough to hold the EOF code for the character encoding. This is sort of like the Standard not specifying exactly how big an `int` is, just that it must be at least 16 bits.

Comment: @user4581301 It specifies the exact type for the standard specializations of char_traits: https://eel.is/c++draft/char.traits.specializations

Comment: @user17732522 It does for `char`, but the other specializations are left up to the implementation.

Comment: @user17732522, you're right, I had both opened and copied the wrong one. Edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The special value `EOF` needs to be of integer type that is wider than the corresponding character type, as it cannot be the same value as any character.

In common scenarios, but not all scenarios(!), it is -1.

The traits class template `std::char_traits` provides a corresponding type for the respective character types: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits

For example, for `char` it is `int`. Which is platform-dependent, but at least 16 bits wide.

Answer (score 2):

When you encounter an undefined term in documentation, try looking a level higher. From the documentation for `std::char_traits<CharT>::eof` (or `std::char_traits::eof`), go to the documentation for `std::char_traits<CharT>` (or `std::char_traits`).

- [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits): *"`int_type`    an integer type that can hold all values of `char_type` plus `EOF` "*
  (Another line specifies that `char_type` is an alias for `CharT`, where `CharT` is the template parameter.)
- [cplusplus.com](https://cplusplus.com/reference/string/char_traits/): *"`int_type`    Integral type that can represent all `charT` values, as well as `eof()`"*
  (This is followed by indicating that when `charT` is `char`, then `int_type` is `int`.)

Note that this type must be wider than the character type (not merely "at least as wide") since the end of file value must be distinct from all character values.

Answer (score 0):

You can print out the EOF types of a given specific implementation.  Note that these could vary by implementation or platform, so be aware of the portability constraints.

The Boost `demangle` is just for legibility.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <boost/core/demangle.hpp>

int main() {
    std::cout << "char is " << boost::core::demangle(typeid(std::char_traits<char>::eof()).name()) << "\n";
    std::cout << "wchar_t is " << boost::core::demangle(typeid(std::char_traits<wchar_t>::eof()).name()) << "\n";
    std::cout << "char16_t is " << boost::core::demangle(typeid(std::char_traits<char16_t>::eof()).name()) << "\n";
    std::cout << "char32_t is " << boost::core::demangle(typeid(std::char_traits<char32_t>::eof()).name()) << "\n";
}
```